Not sure how to analyze a biased bjt transistor in AC
I'm trying to analyze the circuit below.

According to the superposition theorem, I can short circuit one voltage source at a time and then add the voltages both supply in order to find the final voltage of a node.
So, I put it to the test. I shorted the AC voltage source and ran a simulation. These are the results:

They are quite similar to the ones I worked out by means of pen and paper, so no problem here.
However, when I shorted the DC voltage source and ran a simulation, these are the results that occured:

And when both sources are connected, these are the results:

So, why does the superposition theorem not apply here? Clearly adding the DC and AC values does not produce the results shown in the last table. What am I missing?
EDIT: I forgot to add the DC values to the final AC values. My initial approach was wrong since the transistor would be in cutoff (inactive) without biasing. These are the results for the same AC voltage (1V):

I also tried it for an 1 mV signal. Still though my handwritten analysis is somewhat far from the results ADS gives. And I ran my node equations through MATLAB to be precise.
EDIT 2: These are my handwritten calculations:

And these are the results i get from ADS:

What am I missing?

Superposition assumes linear circuits. When you short or open a DC source, does your transistor behave the same?

In an RF circuit, what is important is the correct operation in the center of the band. Therefore, the equivalent circuit for incremental signals in the center of the band must first be drawn. This simplifies the calculations.

The superposition theorem does not apply because a BJT is nonlinear. Superposition is only valid in a circuit consisting entirely of linear elements.
If you want to use superposition here, you need to linearize the system. This can be done under the assumption that the AC signal is small compared to the DC bias, which is the usual way this type of circuit is operated. Just determine what the transistor's characteristics are for small deviations from the DC bias point, then plug those numbers into your transistor model of choice. That, then, can be added to the DC operating point to approximate the full response.

I tried that as well. I applied an 1 mV AC voltage to the circuit. I did an analysis with pen and paper and ran the equations through MATLAB for precision. Still though, the numbers vary.

@kosgian90 Please explain what you mean by "applied an 1 mV AC voltage to the circuit". Was this 1 mV AC on top of your existing DC bias, or with all DC sources shorted as in superposition analysis? The former is valid for a nonlinear circuit, the latter is not.

the first one. I figured it after that trying to superimpose an AC signal on an inactive transistor is completely wrong.

@kosgian90 That should work fine then. By how much did the numbers vary? Are we talking wildly wrong, or just a difference in the seventh decimal place or something?

I will edit my post in order to include my handwritten analysis along with the results i got from MATLAB.

just did it please have a look.
